# How to modify subarray in place

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have:

```
a = [1,2,4,5]
```

I want to modify this array to get:

```
a #=> [1,0,0,0]
```

This can be done with an `each` loop, but I'm trying not to use a loop here. Here's my code:

```
a.values_at(1..3).map! {|i| i = 0}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`fill`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-fill):

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 5]
#=> [1, 2, 4, 5]

a.fill(0, 1)
#=> [1, 0, 0, 0]

a
#=> [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

The above code sets the elements in `a` to `0`, starting at index `1`.